# Boost C++ Thread Local Storage Vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, vector, thread-local-storage

I am creating a tls vector for multi threading and would like to know how to access the vector elements.

Basically I have this created:

```
static boost::thread_specific_ptr< std::string > temp_str;
static boost::thread_specific_ptr< std::vector< std::string > > _Vector_;
```

---

So I suppose this is more of a syntax question, but how can I assign a vector element to the temp tls string I have created?

```
void myFunc()
{

//I need to assign _Vector[i]_ to temp_str
*temp_str = _Vector_.get()[i]; //I know this is an error

}
```

---

Any suggestions?
Thanks :)

Comment: Not the cause of your problem but the identifier `_Vector_` is reserved. Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use. Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

Comment: Interesting...did not know that. Also, I figured out a solution and that was to use the at() method. So:

    _Vector_->get().at(i)